# fetch double level deep relation

Tags: php, yii

I have models: table, column, index, index_column. Relations:

table 1..* column

table 1..* index

index 1..* index_column

Relations defined in model table:

```
        'columns' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AdColumn', 'table_id'),
        'indexes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AdIndex', 'table_id'),
```

Relations defined in model column:

```
        'table' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AdTable', 'table_id'),
```

Relations defined in model index:

```
        'columns' => array(self:: HAS_MANY, 'AdIndexColumn', 'index_id'),
        'table' => array(self:: BELONGS_TO, 'AdTable', 'table_id'),
```

Relations defined in model index_column:

```
        'column' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AdColumn', 'column_id'),
        'index' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AdIndex', 'index_id'),
        'table' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AdTable', 'table_id'),
```

I need to display (using CGridView) list of tables, in each row there should be list of table columns and list of indexes (name + columns).

Models are generated with Gii, so I tried:

```
    $filter = new AdTable('search');
    $filter->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    $dataProvider = $filter->with('columns', 'indexes')->search();
```

And this produced queries:

- for fetching all tables,
- for fetching all columns for above tables
- for fetching all indexes for above tables

But for each index there is another query for fetching index columns. I like those queries put all in one query by Yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is below what you want?

```
$filteredAdTable = AdTable::model()->with(array(
            'indexes' => array(
                'alias' => 'at',
                //'condition' => '',
                //'params' => array(),
                'with' => array(
                    'adIndexColumns'=>array( // 'I changed name this relation from columns to adIndexColumns not to make confusion with the relation columns of AdTable'
                        'alias' => 'aic',
                        //'condition' => '',
                        //'params' => array(),
                    )

                )
            ),

            'columns' => array(
                'alias' => 'ac',
                //'condition' => '',
                //'params' => array(),
            )
        ))->findAll(
            //'condition' => '',
            //'params' => array(),
            );
```

Maybe you should take a look about `together` option

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/527/relational-query-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-with-and-together/

Comment: Similar to mine solution :)